# Derived Table(View) is required

Tags: db2, business-objects

I have the below table in database:

```
"ID Number"  "Balance Amount Type" "Balance Amount"
234             20                    94
234             21                    102
234             22                    100
212             20                    40
212             21                    50
212             22                    60
```

I want to create a below derived table(which is just like views in database) from the above table Universe having below fields :

```
"ID"    "BalAmount if Amount Type=20"     "BalAmount if Amount Type=21"   "BalAmount if Amount Type=22"
234         94                                102                             100
212         40                                50                              60
```

Can you please help me in writing SQL for this derived table, (Database is DB2) ?

Comment: If the database is DB2 why have you tagged with Oracle and MySQL as well?

Comment: You can answer because oracle and DB2 functions are more or less similar

Answer (score 2):

A derived table is nothing more than a regular SELECT:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN amount_type=20 THEN balamount END) type_20_amt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN amount_type=20 THEN balamount END) type_21_amt,
    MAX(CASE WHEN amount_type=20 THEN balamount END) type_22_amt
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    ID
```

**EDIT** added in response to comment:
The max() function is required in order to put all values on one row.  Using the sample data from the question, a query **without** max() would produce:

```
id      type_20_amt    type_21_amt    type_22_amt
--      -----------    -----------    -----------
234              94
234                            102
234                                           100
212              40
212                             50
212                                            60
```

Using max(), however, puts them on one row:

```
id      type_20_amt    type_21_amt    type_22_amt
--      -----------    -----------    -----------
234              94            102            100
212              40             50             60
```

Comment: thanks Joe thats giving the desired result but why you have used max function. Because  I was trying to earlier without using max and the result was not coming as required.

Comment: I updated my answer with further details; let me know if that doesn't work for you.